# Is it possible to convert mysql table names from lowercase to uppercase in linux?

Tags: mysql

I imported a database from Windows to linux and all the tables names are in lowercase.

Is there a way to convert the mysql table names form lowercase to uppercase in linux?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion provided.

Comment: Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: Because the application, which is running on linux, access the tables using their names in uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are addressing the table names in uppercase, which worked in Windows but no longer works on Linux because of case sensitivity.

You *could* rename each  database. However, if you have access to the mySQL configuration, you should also be able to [set `--lower-case-table-names` to `1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

I have no experience with the option, but according to the manual, it makes mySQL behave case-insensitively towards tables, as it does by default on Windows.

Comment: No, in fact windows converted the original tablenames from uppercase to lowercase. When i imported my database schema to linux, i noticed that my application is no longer working properly because it requires that the tablenames are in uppercase.

Comment: @tanya yeah, I understand. As said, using above option you can make the Linux version become case insensitive.

Comment: Now i want to change the tablenames from lowercase to uppercase in linux. I was thinking of manually modifying the .sql file and changing the tablenames to uppercase but it's taking too long :(