# Capitalizing first character of every table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table in MySql and i want first character of every table name in the database to be in capital letter.

Comment: On a live base? For the goodness sake, don't do that!

Comment: i am testing on dumy first

Comment: It's not a matter of testing first. It's a matter of disaster when you change it on a live base.

Comment: i have to change it its necessary i want to know if i can change it or not

Comment: @user2885035 since table names **are** case-sensitive in most cases, don't do this. All your existing applications queries will fail after this

Comment: Tell us why are you need this?

Comment: i have database for my website that worked fine on localhost but when migrated it the server the db displayed error. After searching for a while i realized that the table name are to be changed otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Comment: XY problem, tell us about your situation.

Comment: i have database for my website that worked fine on localhost but when migrated it the server and after completing every process tried to open the webpage it displayed the error.

Comment: I think that is an excpetion inside destruct... Be more specific and update your question.

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047190/is-it-possible-to-convert-mysql-table-names-from-lowercase-to-uppercase-in-linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047190/is-it-possible-to-convert-mysql-table-names-from-lowercase-to-uppercase-in-linux

Comment: The error you show us doesn't seems anyway related to Mysql, but to PHP. if you are exporting script to online there is a chance that encoding of Script files differ or some junk character are coming up. Just make sure you have everything else working fine before changing Table name, as if tablename doesn't match it simply give a query error that table doesn't exists with that name, but not this error.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $pdo = new PDO('...');

    $statement = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES'); // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html

    while ($column = $statement->fetchColumn())
        {
        $pdo->exec("RENAME TABLE `$column` TO `".ucfirst($column)."`"); // dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rename-table.html
        }
```

Comment: can you please explain i know little about db.